# How can I remove a single item from a WordPress navigation menu?

Tags: wordpress

Working on my first plugin.  It has a register activation hook so that when the plugin is activated, it adds a navigation item to a certain menu.  When I deactivate the plugin, I want this link to be removed.  If wp_update_nav_menu_item lets you add an item to a nav menu, what is the complete opposite of this function?

```
function add_frontend_menu_link(){

    if(wp_get_nav_menu_object('Main Navigation')){

        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object('Main Navigation');

        wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, array(
            'menu-item-title' =>  __('Menu'),
            'menu-item-classes' => 'home',
            'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/menu' ), 
            'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));

        $menu_page = array(
          'post_title'    => 'Our Menus',
          'post_name' => 'menu',
          'post_content'  => 'Choose from the menus below to find out what we serve and when we serve it.',
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => 1,
          'post_type' => 'page',

        );

        wp_insert_post($menu_page);

    }

}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'add_frontend_menu_link');

function remove_frontend_menu_link(){

    //What should go here?

}

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'remove_frontend_menu_link');
```

If there is a way to retrieve the id of the menu item that was created, I can store that in an option for the plugin and then call it in the deactivation hook and delete the post by that id.

Comment: Did you try [`remove_menu_page()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page)?

Comment: Doesn't that only work on links in the admin dashboard navigation?  I want to remove links from a front end navigation menu.

Comment: The navigation items are stored as posts, use `WP_Query` to find the post (with post type `nav_menu_item` and your post title) and remove it with `wp_delete_post()`?

Comment: @naththedeveloper is on the right track!  [Here's an answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/140616/10388) describing the approach.

Answer (score 0):

each menu item has its ID and class like ".menu-item-58" , so you can simply hide menu item with required ID.

Comment: That won't work once the plugin has been disabled, the idea is to clean-up after the plugin is de-activated.

Comment: I would rather do it with my plugin than to do it with css.